# How to mark a switch parameter as mandatory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, switch-statement

I'm pretty sure I don't have any other options other than what I've uncovered, but I wanted to pick the collective internet brain.

I prefer to use a **[switch]** parameter when passing boolean values to custom functions. However, I have a few cases in which I wanted to mark the switch parameter as mandatory. This can optionally be accomplished through **[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]** on the parameter. However, I really dislike the UI prompt that shows up. I much prefer throwing an exception.

But, a switch can be either true or false, and the "IsPresent" property makes no distinction. If I pass a switch parameter as **-example:$false**, the switch reports that *$example.IsPresent is false*!

I have resorted to using a [bool]. For example:

```
param
(
   [bool]$theValue = $(throw('You didn't specify the value!'))
);
```

Are there any other tricks I can pull?

Comment: Why not have two switches? `example` and `exampleOff`. Then, when neither `IsPresent` throw an error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a way a `switch` parameter is always mandatory. If you don't specify it, it gets a value of false. If you specify it ( `-var`) it gets a value true and if you specify the value too (`-var:$false`) it gets the value specified.

I can't really think of a situation where it is mandatory to specify a switch. If you don't specify, it is false. Simple as that.

I think what you want is to specifically mention the value of the param to be true or false? If that is the case, the `bool` version that you mention is what I would go for, though it works the same way with `switch` too:

```
param([switch]$a  = $(throw "You didn't specify the value"))
```

And also regarding `$example.IsPresent` - I know it is not intuitive /broken , but it is the same as the value of the switch variable itself. That is how the constructor for `Switch Paramater` is defined and the only property that it has is the `IsPresent`:

> Creates a new SwitchParameter object that includes a Boolean value
>   that identifies whether the switch is present.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.switchparameter.ctor%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If the exception message is what's bothering you, this is the best you're going to get.

Comment: Oops! I had incorrectly concluded that throwing the error when using "Switch" in the parameter list would not work. I have tried this again, and it seems good to go. manojlds's answer is both accurate and very well detailed.